# What is this AS3 syntax? new <object>[];

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I'm trying to use the [SoundAS](https://github.com/treefortress/SoundAS) library in an old Flex 3.6 project. However, upon trying to use it, I get several syntax errors.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before if. SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 362    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before if. SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 377    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before if. SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 440    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before if. SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 443    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before return. SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 438    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace. SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 371    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace. SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 372    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace. SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 430    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before var.    SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 389    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before var.    SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 407    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before var.    SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 426    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before var.    SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 433    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before end of program. SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 447    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before end of program. SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 447    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before end of program. SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 447    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before end of program. SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 447    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before end of program. SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 447    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before for.    SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 408    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before if. SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 390    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before leftbrace.  SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 362    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before leftbrace.  SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 377    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before leftbrace.  SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 440    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before leftbrace.  SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 443    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before loadCompleted.  SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 427    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before loadFailed. SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 434    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before semicolon.  SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 363    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before semicolon.  SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 383    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before semicolon.  SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 393    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before semicolon.  SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 418    Flex Problem
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before semicolon.  SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 446    Flex Problem
1100: Syntax error: XML does not have matching begin and end tags.  SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 447    Flex Problem
1100: Syntax error: XML does not have matching begin and end tags.  SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 447    Flex Problem
1100: Syntax error: XML does not have matching begin and end tags.  SoundManager.as /treefortress/sound line 447    Flex Problem
```

Looking in SoundManager.as, the reported syntax errors are not the actual problem. Instead, the errors all seems to be caused by the use of something like `new <Object>[];`... For instance, `if(!groups){ groups = new <SoundManager>[]; }` on line 350.

I'm not familiar with the syntax used... What is it trying to do, why is it not working in Flash Builder 4.7, and how can I get it to work?

Comment: Looks much like a `Vector` - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html

[Here](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/702) you can see different kinds of declaration and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173845/how-do-i-initialize-a-vector-with-an-array-of-values) some more questions on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @AndreyPopov is right. This variable `groups` is a `Vector` of type `SoundManager`. `var groups:Vector.<SoundManager>` The respective if statement `if` to groups instance is `null` and if so, create a new instance.